# Clean architecture dependency rule and naming objects

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

I am reading the [celan architecture article](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) of Robert c. Martin. So I could not understand the Depencency rule naming in here:

> The overriding rule that makes this architecture work is The
> Dependency Rule. This rule says that source code dependencies can only
> point inwards. Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all
> about something in an outer circle. In particular, the name of
> something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the
> code in the an inner circle. That includes, functions, classes.
> variables, or any other named software entity.

What does it mean "`In particular, the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle. That includes, functions, classes. variables, or any other named software entity`"

I used a class or methed in outer circle, but I can not define a new class or methed in the innner circle. Is true? Or other else.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that In particular, the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle. That includes, functions, classes. variables, or any other named software entity

This means that the inner circle should not know anything from the outer circle in a sense of:

- the Domain layer should not know what database the Data layer is using
- the Domain layer should not know what kind of UI the Presentation layer is rendering to collect/display data

So how does the Domain layer communicate to Data layer if it has something to save or retrieve? **Through the use of interfaces**. It only knows that it needs something to be fetch or save, but it does not know **how**. The actual **implementation is abstracted**. This way, it makes **easier to change** something from the **outer layer without touching the inner layers**. For example:

- You can change the database you are using without touching the Domain/business layer
- You can change how the username or password is being collected from the UI (through input field, voice recognition, etc.) without modifying the Domain layer, it only knows that it will going to receive a string of username and password.

Comment: I understood it as a naming convention at first.